# workaround to hide address bar on ios (ipad)

Tags: ios, fixed, address-bar

i built a [webpage](http://quastenberg.webflow.io) containing only fixed sections filling 100% of the viewport height and width. you can slide through these sections with a menu, kind of like with the fullpagescroll.js library.

the ios address bar always takes 60px of the space and is normally hidden when scrolling down a bit. everybody knows that behaviour.

but because some content is lying at `bottom: 0px;` it can't be seen on pageload. it would show up when scrolling down (which would be okay), but because of the fixed section template scrolling is disabled on my webpage and nobody can see the hidden content.

also vertically centered items are not exactly vertically centered. they are being moved down by 60px.

i know, the ios address bar can't be hidden. but is there maybe a trick to avoid the problems appearing on my webpage?

everything runs beautifully on my desktop. but i also want to have full ipad support. the site renders differently on smaller displays like the iphone so please test this on an ipad.

please help!
thanks in advance!